# Could not fetch JSON from http://anonymous-dtu.site11.com/

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I was looking for a Sample JSON data to test in my app. I found one on http://anonymous-dtu.site11.com/ and I have following code in my app(MainActivity) to retrieve this data:

```
private void getData() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Getting Data....");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.show();
    StringRequest string = new StringRequest
            (Request.Method.GET,
                    "http://anonymous-dtu.site11.com",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                             try{
                                 JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(array.length()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                 for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                                     JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                     String name = obj.getString("Name");
                                     String email = obj.getString("Email");
                                     String phone = obj.getString("Phone");
                                     String city = obj.getString("City");
                                     String country = obj.getString("Country");
                                     ListItem l = new ListItem(name,email,phone,city,country);
                                     listItems.add(l);
                                 }

                                 adapter  = new MyAdapter(listItems, MainActivity.this);
                                 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not fetch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(string);
}
```

But this could not fetch data and catches JSON exception.

Whats wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you post JSON exception?

Comment: @merterpam value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: The url you specified is not an API to return the json object as response, it is just an html page that's why it is throwing json exception. If you want to test the code use this site http://www.mocky.io/. Here you can copy the json string which you want and create the link for it.

Comment: Also for parsing json response to your desired object you can use gson library, you don't need to do it manually. You can refer the below link for more information about the gson usage
http://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library

Comment: @SAJ it worked. Thank you. I understood the problem.

Answer (score 2):

URL in which you're using will return `html` not `json` response. if you want to test with json request. my suggestion would be using the following github API

https://api.github.com/users/google

Answer (score 1):

JSON EXCEPTION is here **Line 483**

> "Country" : "Virgin Islands",
>   United States"

[image]

**correct it as follow**

> "Country" : "Virgin Islands United States"

Comment: Thank you for helping. I got it. It was not returning JSON response

Answer (score 0):

Bro Your Json Response is wrong..

Try Validation of your response here

http://jsoneditoronline.org